# Best way to write "try elsetry" in python?

Tags: python, try-catch

I know 'tryelse' is not a real thing, but my question is about the best way to write out this logic. Given the following example, foo and bar are functions that could break.

I want `aa` to be `foo()`, but if that breaks, I want it to become `bar()`, but if that one breaks too, then set `aa` to 0 as a default.

```
try:
    aa = foo()
elsetry:
    aa = bar()
except e:
    aa = 0
```

Restating my question, what is the best real way to write out this logic in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nested approach is still best:

```
try:
    aa = foo()
except Exception:
    try:
        aa = bar()
    except Exception:
        aa = 0
```

Despite trying to do it with less nesting, the above expresses what you wish to do and it's clear to the reader. If you try to nest more it becomes awkward to write and that's time to rethink your approach. But nesting two try/excepts is fine.

You can also write:

```
try:
    aa = foo()
except Exception:
    aa = None

if aa is None:
    try:
        aa = bar()
    except Exception:
        aa = 0
```

but somehow that doesn't look right (to me at least). It would also be incorrect in case `foo()` can return `None` as a valid value for `aa`.

Comment: The second solution is awkward.  It doesn't cut down on indentation and also makes it less clear that you want to try `bar` only if `foo` fails.  +1 for the first solution (a.k.a the right approach :)

Comment: I don't plan to have more than two breaking functions like you have here, but just out of curiousity, what would be best if I had five or ten different breakable functions that I would want this functionality with?

Comment: @StevenRogers: you could add all functions to a list, iterate over the list and call each function with a try/except around it. You'd then break out of the loop as soon as the first function succeeds to give you a value.

Answer (score 4):

If you have either a long chain of these, or a *dynamic* list of alternatives, you probably want to use a `for` loop:

```
for func in funcs:
    try:
        aa = func()
        break
    except:
        pass
else:
    aa = 0
```

---

Note that either way, you probably don't *really* want a bare `except` here. Usually you're only expecting some specific class of errors (e.g., `ValueError` or `LookupError`), and anything else shouldn't mean "silently try the next one" but "show the programmer that something unexpected went wrong". But you know how to fix that.

---

You could of course wrap that up in a function if you need to use it repeatedly:

```
def try_funcs(*funcs, defval=0, ok_exceptions=Exception):
    for func in funcs:
        try:
            return func()
        except ok_exceptions:  # ok_exceptions can also be a tuple of exception classes.
            pass
    return defval
```

---

Of course, as mentioned in the comments, this does require that everything you want to try be a function of no arguments. What if you want to try `spam(42)`, then `eggs(beans)` if that fails? Or something that isn't even a function call but some other expression, like `foo[bar]`?

That's the same as the general case that occurs all over Python: you use `partial` to bind in the arguments for the first case, or write a wrapper function with `lambda` for the second:

```
result = try_funcs(partial(spam, 42), partial(eggs, beans), lambda: foo[bar])
```

---

However, if you just have a static two or three alternatives to try, [Simon Visser's simple nested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27325699/908494) is much clearer.

---

If you're asking *why* the language doesn't have your `tryelse`… well, I know it's come up on the python-ideas/-dev lists and elsewhere a few times, and been discussed, so you might want to search for more detailed/authoritative answers. But I think it comes down to this: While it's theoretically possible to come up with cases that might look cleaner with a `tryelse`, every example anyone's ever given is either fine as-is, or should obviously be refactored, so there's no compelling argument to change the grammar, reserve a new keyword, etc.

Comment: @mgilson: I was just in the middle of adding the same thing but with a different name and more explanation. I've kept your name (and also using `Exception` instead of `(Exception,)`, as I was going to…) because it's more readable. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice idea! However its much harder to use when functions take different arguments

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski: Not "much harder"; you just need to use `partial` (when it's really just a function call) or write a `lambda` function (when it's an arbitrary expression)—exactly the same as _any_ case where you need to pass a nullary callable, which happens all over Python (e.g., Tkinter or Twisted callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way to do that:

```
try:
    aa = foo()
except:
    try:
        aa = bar()
    except:
        aa = 0
```

This is what you do when you dont have elif statement like in JavaScript:

```
if if_condition:
   code
else:
   if elif_condition:
       code
   else:
        code
```

Comment: Please do not advocate use of bare `except`.  Catch `Exception` or something more specific.

Comment: @roippi: He's not advocating it, he's just copying it from the question, as every other answer here does…